# Completion of 10 years UK ban

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, visa-bans, proof-of-employment

I was banned for 10 years by the UK for a document my company submitted via an agent in support of my UK application in 2013.

The company didn't give the directive for the agent handling the application to falsify any documents because we have a legitimate company with lots of agents nationwide selling our products. We have over 7,800 agents scattered across Nigeria at that time. So, it doesn't make sense to me.

Fast forward to 2023, I got job as a healthcare worker in the UK 3 days to the expiration of the ban period but I have not submitted my application as a skilled worker yet, because I want to make sure the ban expires before I do. Now the ban has expired on the 4th of February 2023.

My lawyer has written a letter as to what happened at the time and pleaded my innocence because they're is absolutely no way I can discover that the company document had been falsified but he wrote that I take full responsibility for the action and that I have served the 10 year ban.

What chances do I have to be issued a skilled-worker visa as this job of mine is in the a shortage list in the UK?

Meanwhile, I have done my IELTS, Online Care Certification, Practical Care Certification, Police  Character, and TB Test and paid for the visa application (£600).

What is left is just to upload my documents and submit my application.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: the only way to know for sure if you will be issued a visa or not is to apply for one and see if you are accepted or rejected.

Comment: What type of health care worker? If you’re a (highly) qualified medical professional with a job offer from a Home Office-approved UK health and care sector employer, you probably stand a pretty good chance of success

Comment: It's a carer job offer from the Home Office-approved UK Care sector employer.